# Как использовать переменную в названии базы SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite3

Подскажите, возможно ли использовать значение переменной в названии базы SQLite?
Имеется переменная spisok:

```
['1','2','3','4',...,'98','99']
```

Дальше запускается цикл:

```
for i in range(len(spisok)):
```

Можно ли, используя sqlite3.connect создавать файлы .bd с именем i? Чтобы в папке были файлы: 1.bd, 2.bd, 3.bd, ... , 98.bd, 99.bd?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: если очень коротко — можно, надеюсь Вы сами знаете зачем, и не забывайте закрывать открытые соединения

Comment: Зачем? Какова конечная цель?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov был молод и глуп. По сути таблицы нужно было создавать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, например так:

```
import sqlite3
for i in range(1, 100):
    db_t = sqlite3.connect(f"{i}.db")
    db_t.close()
```

Название файла генерируется через формат строки, важно не забывать закрывать соединение. Переменную i я считаю через range, но можно подставить ваш список. Разницы нет никакой.